# Pandas Year/Month/Date Separation For Improving Relevance

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to use MinMaxScaler function of SKLearn on time series data, in order to use it I think I need my values to be on `dtype int64, float64` for that I can convert a separate date and time from datetime value like

```
                 DATETIME 
0     2013-02-13 00:00:00 
1     2013-02-13 00:30:00 
2     2013-02-13 01:00:00 
3     2013-02-13 01:30:00 
4     2013-02-13 02:00:00 
5     2013-02-13 02:30:00 
6     2013-02-13 03:00:00 
7     2013-02-13 03:30:00 
8     2013-02-13 04:00:00 
9     2013-02-13 04:30:00 
10    2013-02-13 05:00:00 
11    2013-02-13 05:30:00
```

What I tried so far was separating the time and and date but the releavance isn't even close to 0.5
[image]

This is why I want to separate the years, months and days maybe the days would have relevance of 0.5 or more.

But how do I do that from pandas to transforming it into the dtypes i mentioned before?

I know I could separate it like this

```
series['YEAR'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(series['DATE']).year
series['MONTH'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(series['DATE']).month
series['DAY'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(series['DATE']).day
```

but how do i turn them to acceptable data for MinMax?

Target output it to convert this:

```
Y     M  D   T
2013  2  3   00:00:00
```

to dtypes that can fit to the code below

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(series)
series = scaler.transform(series)
```

Comment: The code for separation is wrong. What is your expected output?

Comment: @harvpan I have added it to the question

Comment: is `DATETIME` index?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are doing `MinMaxScaler` on date feature but instead of exploding the date, just convert them to unix timestamp. That will be a better way to solve your issue.

Comment: I already did this but its relevance to my data is too low which is why Im looking to explode it expecting that it may have a better relevance score that the whole unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, `DATETIME` is an index, so you need:

```
df['Y'] = df.index.to_series().dt.year
df['M'] = df.index.to_series().dt.month
df['D'] = df.index.to_series().dt.day
```

Output:

```
                        Y  M   D
DATETIME                        
2013-02-13 00:00:00  2013  2  13
2013-02-13 00:30:00  2013  2  13
2013-02-13 01:00:00  2013  2  13
2013-02-13 01:30:00  2013  2  13
2013-02-13 02:00:00  2013  2  13
2013-02-13 02:30:00  2013  2  13
2013-02-13 03:00:00  2013  2  13
2013-02-13 03:30:00  2013  2  13
2013-02-13 04:00:00  2013  2  13
2013-02-13 04:30:00  2013  2  13
2013-02-13 05:00:00  2013  2  13
2013-02-13 05:30:00  2013  2  13
```